# Bridging Adapter in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for KVM

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04, bridge, libvirt

Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with libvert/KVM installed. I have 2 virtual machines that I need need to be on the same LAN as the host. The host has two physical interfaces eth0 and eth1. eth1 is not in use. I would like eth0 to have a static assigned IP and act as a bridge for my VM's.

Prior to setting up the bridge my /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.5.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.5.254
    dns-nameservers 10.0.5.1
```

Everything works as expected under this configuration. However, When I apply the below captioned configuration:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.5.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.5.254
    dns-nameservers 10.0.5.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

Under this configuration I can ping internal hosts by IP and name. Name resolution works as expected. Attempting to ping an external hosts yields "No route to host."

Here is ifconfig -a after the bridge configuration is applied.

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:da:29:8f  
          inet addr:10.0.5.5  Bcast:10.0.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:feda:298f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1433248 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:63079 (63.0 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:da:29:8f  
          inet addr:10.0.5.107  Bcast:10.0.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:feda:298f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13632 errors:0 dropped:122 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2008747 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:119540 (119.5 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:dfa00000-dfa20000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:da:29:8e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:df900000-df920000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:66095 (66.0 KB)  TX bytes:66095 (66.0 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c2:dd:f8:44:eb:2d  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Ultimately, I want eth0 to have static 10.0.5.5 and put both of my VM's on this interface with statically assigned 10.0.5.6-7. What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What is the output of `ip route ls`?

Comment: `default via 10.0.5.254 dev eth0  proto static 
    default via 10.0.5.254 dev br0  metric 100 
    10.0.5.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.5.5 
    10.0.5.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.5.107 metric 1 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1000 
    192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1`

Comment: Why would eth0 have ip address 10.0.5.107?

Comment: @MarkWagner - I haven't the slightest clue. I don't understand where that address is coming from. I presume its DHCP assigned although it shouldn't be. What should the IP config look like on the physical interface eth0 when it is a bridge port?

Comment: Is networkmanager installed?

Comment: @sciurus I think you just hit it on the head. I did not install `networkmanager` explicitly but I installed `ubuntu-desktop` and neglected to suppress `--no-install-recommends` - would this have installed networkmanager? As it turns out, I blew up my installation and started over as it was just a lab setup, so I am unable to check. But if networkmanager was installed and I was editing in /etc/network/interfaces I suspect this may have been the cause?